# Shortest distance from a point to a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Question: there's this point **v = (2,5,-1)** that is not on the subspace W. W is given by

```
{(x,x,y) ; x,y∈R}.
```

Determine the shortest distance from any point on W to the point v.

My approach is to first use the gram-schmidt formula to find w', the projection of v onto w. And then calculate the distance between w' and v. (using the distance formula)

It would be helpful to know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: That is one way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Math1000 are there other ways?